# Calling ModelSim commands from SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

Is there a way to call a ModelSim command (e.g. `force -freeze`) from SystemVerilog?

Comment: Could you expand your example, are you trying to do some thing like : `initial begin #2m force -freeze end`

Comment: yes, I'd expect something like: initial begin #2m $simulator("force -freeze /tb/i_dut/some_signal 0 0"); end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package `mti_fli` that you can import lets you call modelsim commands using the SystemVerilog DPI. Look in "*Simplified Import of Library Functions*" in the User Manual.

However for large designs, I would strongly recommend using Verilog's force statement directly for performance reasons. Anytime you have to look up a signal by string name at run time prevents many optimizations to keep those names available.

Comment: Does the verilog's force command work when the DUT is written in VHDL? I've tried it already and it failed, but maybe I just did something wrong.

Comment: No, that's the first you mentioned using VHDL. Using $signal_force or mti_Command() will work with VHDL.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to force a signal, you can use the $signal_force system task. Have a look in the ModelSim manual on its input parameters.